# positioning absolute from the bottom

Tags: html, css

My webpage looks fine on my screen. I have all the divs placed with the `body` tag, with the body having relative poisoning, so that it can act like a container for the webpage. The only thing i can't get the divs within the body to do is position absolute from the bottom. I don't know why this won't work. Because when i visit the page on a different screen the divs are positioned not all the way down when i use top, so I'm trying to use bottom positioning instead.

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="statement_div"> <p id="statement"> Access to Every Bad Movie Ever. </p>  </div>

    <div id="signin_button"> <span style="position: relative; top: 3px"> Sign In </span> </div>
    <div id="create_account_button"> <span style="position: relative; top: 3px"> Create Account </span> </div> 
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
background-repeat: no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
min-width: 1200px;
position: relative;
}

#signin_button {
width: 12%;
min-width: 150px;
height: 40px;
color: white;
background-color: #FF3030;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 70%;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: Futura;
}

#create_account_button {
width: 16%;
min-width: 150px;
height: 40px;
color: white;
background-color: #3399FF;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 83%;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: Futura;
}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u try using `position: fixed`? eg:

```
#signin_button {
    width: 12%;
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #FF3030;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed; /* this is the only thing you need to do differently */
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 70%;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Futura;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

body should have min-height set to 100vh (100% viewport height)

```css
body {
background-repeat: no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
min-width: 1200px;
position: relative;
/* HERE'S THE DEAL */  min-height: 100vh;
}

#signin_button {
width: 12%;
min-width: 150px;
height: 40px;
color: white;
background-color: #FF3030;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 70%;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: Futura;
}

#create_account_button {
width: 16%;
min-width: 150px;
height: 40px;
color: white;
background-color: #3399FF;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 83%;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: Futura;
}
```

```html
<div id="statement_div">
  <p id="statement"> Access to Every Bad Movie Ever.</p>
</div>

<div id="signin_button">
  <span>Sign In</span>
</div>

<div id="create_account_button">
  <span>Create Account</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `position: relative;` style from the `body` tag as that is pretty much unnecessary and its causing issue as that time the height of the body is taking the 100% content height and not the screen.